# Is there a way to add a Name tag to a created snapshot using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm not having any luck finding this browsing through the API documentation. I would be surprised if this wasn't possible. I have this to create a snapshot using boto:

```
conn.create_snapshot(volume_id, "This shows up in the description column")
```

This works, but I would like to properly tag the snapshot with a {Name: "my tag"}. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this while creating the snapshot? If that's not possible, is it possible to add a tag to the snapshot object after creation?

Answer (score 9):

It's not possible to add tags when you create a Snapshot.  The EC2 API does not support that.  However, you can easily tag a Snapshot after creating it.  There are a couple of ways to do that.

The first uses the `Snapshot` object returned by the `create_snapshot` method:

```
snapshot = conn.create_snapshot(volume_id, "This shows up in the description column")
snapshot.add_tags({'foo': 'bar', 'fie': 'bas'})
```

Or, you can use the generic `create_tags` method which can be used to add tags to any tag-able resource:

```
conn.create_tags('snap-12345678', {'foo': 'bar', 'fie': 'baz'})
```

Comment: Interestingly, it's possible to set tags for RDS snapshots during creation-time. Even boto supports it.

Comment: Inconsistencies across API's is a thing.

Comment: In fact your solution gives me this error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add_tags' when I want to add a tag to snapshot
`

Answer (score 1):

As per [this AWS announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tag-amazon-ebs-snapshots-on-creation-and-implement-stronger-security-policies/) it is possible to pass tags when creating the snapshot since April 2018.

Here is a snippet doing just that:

```
snap = ec.create_snapshot(
    Description = "Recent Snapshot",
    VolumeId = volume_id,
    TagSpecification = [{
        'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
        'Tags': [
            {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': snapshot},
            {'Key': 'InstanceId', 'Value': instance_id}
        ]
    }]
)
```

As you can see, the former `ec2.create_tags()` call has been merged into this.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it using the `create_tags` method only (the `add_tags` method raised the `AttributeError` error as mentioned by JavaQueen above in comments).

Example:

```
snapshot = conn.create_snapshot(volume_id, "This shows up in the description column")

conn.create_tags(
            Resources=[
                snapshot['SnapshotId'],
            ],
            Tags=[
                {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'myTagValue'}
            ]
 )
```

Inspired from [Eddie Trejo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8224598/eddie-trejo) contribution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44796462/1973233

Note: you may have to update the underlying policy to be granted to the `Allow: ec2:CreateSnapshot` permission.