# Add tag while creating EBS snapshot using boto3

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

Is it possible to add a tag when invoking the create_snapshot() method in boto3? When I run the following code:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')

root_snap_resp = client.create_snapshot(
    Description='My snapshot description',
    VolumeId='vol-123456',
    Tags=[{'Key': 'Test_Key', 'Value': 'Test_Value'}]
)
```

I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "Tags", must be one of: DryRun, VolumeId, Description
```

Is the only way to add a tag after the fact using the create_tags() method?

Comment: Yes. `create_tags` is the only way to add a tag for a EC2 resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In April, 2018, the original answer (and the question itself) were made obsolete...

> You can now specify tags for EBS snapshots as part of the API call that creates the resource or via the Amazon EC2 Console when creating an EBS snapshot.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tag-amazon-ebs-snapshots-on-creation-and-implement-stronger-security-policies/

...unless you are using an older version of an SDK that does not implement the feature.

The same announcement extended resource-level permissions to snapshots.

<strike>The underlying [`CreateSnapshot` action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSnapshot.html) in the EC2 API doesn't have any provision for adding tags simultaneously with the creation of the snapshot.  You have to go back and tag it after creating it.</strike>

Comment: As of Apr 2018, `CreateSnapshot` allows snapshot tagging at creation time: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tag-amazon-ebs-snapshots-on-creation-and-implement-stronger-security-policies/

Answer (score 3):

```py
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
volume = ec2.Volume('vol-xxxxxxxxxx')

snapshot = ec2.create_snapshot(
    VolumeId = volume.id,
    TagSpecifications = [
        {
            'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
            'Tags': volume.tags,
        },
    ],
    Description = 'Snapshot of volume ({})'.format(volume.id),
)
```

@fender4645 You can now specify tags for EBS snapshots as part of the API call that creates the resource.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my backup script:

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime

ec = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    reservations = ec.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {'Name':'tag:Backup', 'Values':['Yes','yes']}
        ]
    ).get(
        'Reservations', []
    )

    instances = sum(
        [
            [i for i in r['Instances']]
            for r in reservations
        ], [])

    print "Found %d instances that need backing up" % len(instances)

    to_tag = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for instance in instances:
        try:
            retention_days = [
                int(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
                if t['Key'] == 'Retention'][0]
        except IndexError:
            retention_days = 30

        for dev in instance['BlockDeviceMappings']:
            if dev.get('Ebs', None) is None:
                continue
            vol_id = dev['Ebs']['VolumeId']
            print "Found EBS volume %s on instance %s" % (
                vol_id, instance['InstanceId'])

            snap = ec.create_snapshot(
                VolumeId=vol_id,
            )

            to_tag[retention_days].append(snap['SnapshotId'])

            print "Retaining snapshot %s of volume %s from instance %s for %d days" % (
                snap['SnapshotId'],
                vol_id,
                instance['InstanceId'],
                retention_days,
            )

            snapshot_name = 'N/A'
            if 'Tags' in instance:
                for tags in instance['Tags']:
                    if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
                        snapshot_name = tags["Value"]

            print "Tagging snapshot with Name: %s" % (snapshot_name)

            ec.create_tags(
                Resources=[
                    snap['SnapshotId'],
                ],
                Tags=[
                    {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': snapshot_name},
                    {'Key': 'Description', 'Value': "Created by lambda automated backups"}
                ]
            )

    for retention_days in to_tag.keys():
        delete_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
        delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print "Will delete %d snapshots on %s" % (len(to_tag[retention_days]), delete_fmt)
        ec.create_tags(
            Resources=to_tag[retention_days],
            Tags=[
                {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt}
            ]
        )
```

And this this my script to delete old backups that have "delete_on" tag with value of today in the YYYY-MM-DD format

```
import boto3
import re
import datetime

ec = boto3.client('ec2')
iam = boto3.client('iam')

"""
This function looks at *all* snapshots that have a "DeleteOn" tag containing
the current day formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. This function should be run at least
daily.
"""

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    account_ids = list()
    try:
        """
        You can replace this try/except by filling in `account_ids` yourself.
        Get your account ID with:
        > import boto3
        > iam = boto3.client('iam')
        > print iam.get_user()['User']['Arn'].split(':')[4]
        """
        iam.get_user()
    except Exception as e:
        # use the exception message to get the account ID the function executes under
        account_ids.append(re.search(r'(arn:aws:sts::)([0-9]+)', str(e)).groups()[1])


    delete_on = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    filters = [
        {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['DeleteOn']},
        {'Name': 'tag-value', 'Values': [delete_on]},
    ]
    snapshot_response = ec.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=account_ids, Filters=filters)


    for snap in snapshot_response['Snapshots']:
        print "Deleting snapshot %s" % snap['SnapshotId']
        ec.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snap['SnapshotId'])
```