# Adding AWS Tag in Boto3 python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Python noob here. I recently came across a blog site that taught a lesson on how to automate EBS snapshots using lambda & python. The script runs perfect and technically does everything I want except I can't figure out how to add AWS tags in boto3 lib.

```
import boto3
import datetime
import pytz
import os

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("\n\nAWS snapshot backups starting at %s" % datetime.datetime.now())
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(
        Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])

    for instance in instances:
        instance_name = filter(lambda tag: tag['Key'] == 'Name', instance.tags)[0]['Value']

        for volume in ec2.volumes.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'attachment.instance-id', 'Values': [instance.id]}]):
            description = 'scheduled-%s-%s' % (instance_name,
                datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M"))

            if volume.create_snapshot(VolumeId=volume.volume_id, Description=description):
                print("Snapshot created with description [%s]" % description)

        for snapshot in volume.snapshots.all():
            retention_days = int(os.environ['retention_days'])
            if snapshot.description.startswith('scheduled-') and ( datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=None) - snapshot.start_time.replace(tzinfo=None) ) > datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days):
                print("\t\tDeleting snapshot [%s - %s]" % ( snapshot.snapshot_id, snapshot.description ))
                snapshot.delete()

    print("\n\nAWS snapshot backups completed at %s" % datetime.datetime.now())
    return True
```

Please can someone explain how I can add tags to the ebs snapshots being created by this script.

my educational guess is that it should be in this portion of the script. because thats where the description is being created. so could i in theory just add a variable named tag = ec2.Tag('resource_id','key','value') ?

```
    for volume in ec2.volumes.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'attachment.instance-id', 'Values': [instance.id]}]):
        description = 'scheduled-%s-%s' % (instance_name,
            datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M"))
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add tags while doing `volume.create_snapshot`

replace

```
if volume.create_snapshot(VolumeId=volume.volume_id, Description=description):
    print("Snapshot created with description [%s]" % description)
```

with

```
if volume.create_snapshot(
    VolumeId=volume.volume_id,
    Description=description,
    TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'Owner',
                    'Value': 'RaGe'
                },
                {
                    'Key': 'date', 
                    'Value': datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
):
    print("Snapshot created with description [%s]" % description)
```

[reference](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_snapshot)

This results in:

[image]

Comment: I see thank you! but that does leave me another question.. How would I create a unique id for the value portion? for example if I wanted to use a date as a string.

i figured: datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") < was already promoting a string date but it doesnt seem to work in lambda.

Comment: bare with me sorry im noob. I took your string example and changed it to
`'Key': 'date',
 'Value': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` 

i get an error   "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function'"

Comment: so did some research looks like this question answers the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659418/add-tag-while-creating-ebs-snapshot-using-boto3 
the EC2 API doesn't have any provision for adding tags simultaneously with the creation of the snapshot.

Comment: The answer you linked to is not valid anymore. AWS introduced the API to add snapshot tags during snapshot creation very recently (April 2018) see: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tag-amazon-ebs-snapshots-on-creation-and-implement-stronger-security-policies/

Comment: That said, I got the `ResourceType` wrong, edited my answer to fix. also added a datetime tag. I just tried it out and works fine for me.